# Replace all characters except first one and whitespaces

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

Hi
I trying do something like that:

I've got some string - `'Hello World!'` for example.
And I want replace all character in it except the first one and white spaces.

so... result will be: `"H.... ......"`;
I don't want delete it, just replacing with `"."` or other character.

I tried doing this with `preg_replace` but with no results.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it like so:

```
$hidden = preg_replace('/(?!^)\S/', '.', $text);
```

It works by ensuring that we aren't at the beginning of the string with a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for the [start of string anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), then matches a non-whitespace character using the [negated whitespace character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#shorthand).

Comment: This solved my issue, I wanted all my words to replace by dot( . ) or by asterisk ( * )

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('/(?<!^)\S/', '.', $s)
```

Comment: You are the gratest! Thank You very much. It work's perfectly

Comment: does it required "<" for 'start of string' negation?